# php wordpress shortcode in excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for away to use shortcodes in post excerpts that will be called via:

```
 $post_object->post_excerpt;
```

I have the function set up to pull the excerpts but I am struggling to pull the shortcode. at the moment it just returns a string EG: "[short]foo[/short]".
Does anyone know what I need to add to functions.php to allow shortcode usage in this way?
WP 3.6

EDIT: Also the call to the excerpt is nested inside an already existing shortcode function, which works fine.

Edit 2:

To clarify, I am using 2 function. One to create a format for the page "box":

```
//create box shortcode
function box( $atts, $content = null) {
    $p_id = $atts['post'];
    $p = get_post($p_id);
    $output = '<div class="box"><a href="'.get_permalink($p_id).'"><div class="box_inner"><h1>'.$p->post_title.'</h1><p>'.$p->post_excerpt.'</p></div></a></div>';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode("box", "box");
```

And one to create an icon "char" (this is the function I want to use on the excerpt in the short code above):

```
//big text for icons shortcode
function icon( $atts, $content = null) {
    return '<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 100px;>'.$content.'</p>';
}
add_shortcode("icon", "icon");
```

I may be way off base here, is it even possible to use shortcodes in this fashion? and if so how do I stop the excerpt from ignoring the shortcode format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is looking.

I made a school boy error here.
I had the filter:

```
add_filter( 'post_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

But forgot to use:

```
apply_filters('post_excerpt', $p->post_excerpt);
```

Now works fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve shortcodes, you will need to run your content (the excerpt in your case) through the [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) API function.

So I'd imagine it as something like `$xrpt=do_shortcode($xrpt);`

Answer (score 0):

U might also need to use add_action() in order to register a hook to your shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

Add these 4 lines to your `functions.php` file for complete and comprehensive results:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```